# Grabbing a specific hash in an array that meets a specific criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a huge array full of a bunch of hashes.  What I need to do is single out one index hash from the array that meets a specific criteria. (doing this due to an rspec test, but having trouble singling out one of them)

My array is like this

```
[
  {
                      "name" => "jon doe",
                     "team" => "team2",
                     "price" => 2000,
      "eligibility_settings" => {}
  },
  {
                      "name" => "jonny doe",
                     "team" => "team1",
                     "value" => 2000,
      "eligibility_settings" => {
                     "player_gender" => male,
                    "player_max_age" => 26,
                    "player_min_age" => 23,
          "established_union_only" => true
      }
  },
  {
                      "name" => "jonni doe",
                     "team" => "team3",
                     "price" => 2000,
      "eligibility_settings" => {}
  },  
]
```

I need to single out the second one, based on its eligibility settings.  I just took three of them from my array, have lots more, so simple active record methods like (hash.second) won't work in this instance.

I've tried things like

```
players.team.map(&:hash).find{ |x| x[ 'eligibility_settings?' ] == true}
```

However when I try this, I get a `nil` response. (which is odd)

I've also looked into using the ruby `detect` method, which hasn't gotten me anywhere either

```
Players.team.map(&:hash).['hash.seligibiltiy_settings'].detect { true }
```

Would anybody have any idea what to do with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Notes

```
players.team.map(&:hash).find{ |x| x[ 'eligibility_settings?' ] == true}
Players.team.map(&:hash).['hash.seligibiltiy_settings'].detect { true }
```

- Is is `players` or `Players` ?
- Why is it plural?
- If you can call `map` on `team`, it probably should be plural
- Why do you convert to a hash?
- `eligibility_settings?` isn't a key in your hash. `eligibility_settings` is
- `eligibility_settings` can be a hash, but it cannot be `true`
- If you want to check if it isn't empty, use `!h['eligibility_settings'].empty?`

## Possible solution

You could use :

```
data = [
  {
    'name' => 'jon doe',
    'team' => 'team2',
    'price' => 2000,
    'eligibility_settings' => {}
  },
  {
    'name' => 'jonny doe',
    'team' => 'team1',
    'value' => 2000,
    'eligibility_settings' => {
      'player_gender' => 'male',
      'player_max_age' => 26,
      'player_min_age' => 23,
      'established_union_only' => true
    }
  },
  {
    'name' => 'jonni doe',
    'team' => 'team3',
    'price' => 2000,
    'eligibility_settings' => {}
  }
]

p data.find { |h| !h['eligibility_settings'].empty? }

# {"name"=>"jonny doe", "team"=>"team1", "value"=>2000, "eligibility_settings"=>{"player_gender"=>"male", "player_max_age"=>26, "player_min_age"=>23, "established_union_only"=>true}}
```

If `h['eligibility_settings']` can be `nil`, you can use :

```
data.find { |h| !h['eligibility_settings'].blank? }
```

or

```
data.find { |h| h['eligibility_settings'].present? }
```

Comment: wow. Very thorough answer. Thank you so much for helping me with this. definitely useful, and I learned a bit about your approach. Thank you!